# How did Google Maps implement several click-event-handle on one image?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom-events

I found out that in Google Maps, the control panel is a whole image:
[image]

But when you click on different position of it, you can get different things done. I'm wondering how can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's one image, but there are a bunch of objects that use it as their background but in different positions. They're callled [sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript `onclick` event object has the information about click coordinates. Here is an example of how to extract and use that information:

*Stolen from here: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2006/09/02/click-image-and-get-coordinates-with-javascript/*

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
function point_it(event){
    pos_x = event.offsetX?(event.offsetX):event.pageX-document.getElementById("pointer_div").offsetLeft;
    pos_y = event.offsetY?(event.offsetY):event.pageY-document.getElementById("pointer_div").offsetTop;
    document.getElementById("cross").style.left = (pos_x-1) ;
    document.getElementById("cross").style.top = (pos_y-15) ;
    document.getElementById("cross").style.visibility = "visible" ;
    document.pointform.form_x.value = pos_x;
    document.pointform.form_y.value = pos_y;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="pointform" method="post">
<div id="pointer_div" onclick="point_it(event)" style = "background-image:url('sun.jpg');width:500px;height:333px;">
<img src="point.gif" id="cross" style="position:relative;visibility:hidden;z-index:2;"></div>
You pointed on x = <input type="text" name="form_x" size="4" /> - y = <input type="text" name="form_y" size="4" />
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML Image Maps. These define areas in your image that are clickable and distinguishable from one another.

See also the following links:

- http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/imagemap.shtml
- http://www.elated.com/articles/creating-image-maps/